# Nginx Reverse Proxy for Web Socket giving error failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream,

Tags: websocket, nginx-reverse-proxy

I recently added websockets to my Nginx reverse proxy on GCP.  However, nginx proxy gives me an error "Connection refused while connecting to upstream. upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/apisocket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NrYupkL", .  Not sure what us wrong.
The Websocket works fine if I bypass Nginx.For some reason the error.og shows it as trying to connect to upstream on port 3000 instead of port 4000

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
     default upgrade;
     '' close;
 }

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;


    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost www.localhost.com;
        gzip on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types application/javascript application/json text/css text/xml;
        gzip_comp_level 5;
        gzip_min_length 256;


    location / {
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:3000/api;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location /api {
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:3000/api;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }


    location /api2 {
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:4000/api2;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            # Websocket support
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

    }
}
```